# Binary tree traversal not working

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to create a binary tree and traverse it.
Problem is that, `CreateBT()` makes the tree correctly but `TreeTraverse(BTNode node)` only print `root` of the tree and its 2 child no matter which ever traversal i use.

I even checked nodes and its child using ( *commented in the code* )

```
//btn is binaryTreeNode
System.out.println("btn : "+btn.getData()+" - right : "+btn.getRight()+" - left "+btn.getLeft());
```

and output is as expected :

```
btn : 0 - right : Data_S.BTNode@1ba0281 - left Data_S.BTNode@fa6824
btn : 1 - right : Data_S.BTNode@1cb1d37 - left Data_S.BTNode@1eb424b
btn : 2 - right : Data_S.BTNode@4d8040 - left Data_S.BTNode@1f14fd
btn : 3 - right : null - left Data_S.BTNode@9b04ac
btn : 4 - right : null - left null
btn : 5 - right : null - left null
btn : 6 - right : null - left null
```

I am really messed up in finding the error, can someone help me please??

**Code**

```
void CreateBT()
    {
        int nodeCnt = 0;
        BTNode leftN, rightN;
        while(!BTq.isQueueEmpty())
        {
            BTNode btn = new BTNode(BTq.deQueue());

            if(root == null)
                root = btn;

            int leftNodeIndex = getLeftIndex(nodeCnt);
            int rightNodeIndex = getRightIndex(nodeCnt++);

            if(leftNodeIndex >= BTq.queueArray.length)
                btn.setLeft(null);
            else
            {
                leftN = new BTNode(BTq.queueArray[leftNodeIndex]);
                btn.setLeft(leftN);
            }


            if(rightNodeIndex >= BTq.queueArray.length)
                btn.setRight(null);
            else
            {
                    rightN = new BTNode(BTq.queueArray[rightNodeIndex]);
                    btn.setRight(rightN);
            }

        //System.out.println("btn : "+btn.getData()+" - right : "+btn.getRight()+" - left "+btn.getLeft());
        }

        TreeTraverse(root);
    }


public void TreeTraverse(BTNode node)
    {
        if(node == null)
            return;
            TreeTraverse(node.left);
    System.out.println(node.getData());
    TreeTraverse(node.right);

    }
```

**Output**

```
1
0
2
```

**Input Array data**

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @slim :  while i appreciate ur link, but my question is not a homework and also, its has a *definite* answer....not an opinion....so i think it does belong to SO! :)

Comment: Regardless of whether it's homework, it's something you can solve yourself using the techniques described in that page. Most directly - stepping through the code in a debugger.

Comment: my problem was in the logic.....debugger can not track that!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the children of a node, as in your code

```
leftN = new BTNode(BTq.queueArray[leftNodeIndex]);
btn.setLeft(leftN);
```

you create a node and in the next while loop, you create another node by
`BTNode btn = new BTNode(BTq.deQueue());`

and these two nodes are different while they are supposed to be the same, so you may set the children of root right, but in the next loop, you add the children to the node you create which is `btn` instead of the one you create in the previous loop which is `lefttN`.

**Update:**
if you print the node and its children, like `System.out.println("btn : "+btn+" - right : "+btn.getRight()+" - left "+btn.getLeft());` you may find that root's left node is different from what you print in the second line.

The problem is that you create a node `a(0)` for example, and set its children `b(1)` and `c(2)`, and in the next loop you create a node `d(1)` and set its children .... while `b` is the left child of `a`, and `d` should also be the left child of `a`, but `b` and `d` are different, you set the `children` of `d` instead of `b`, so `b` doesn't have children, and when you call `TreeTraverse` , it will stop at the second layer.

What you need to do is to set the children of `b` instead of `d`

Comment: `BTNode(BTq.queueArray[leftNodeIndex]);` just creates a node, setting data in it....which is `deQueued` from queue...`setLeft` just sets the pointer....all this is done under single instance and then next instance of `while` executes!

Comment: you mean `BTq.queueArray[leftNodeIndex]` will execute dequeue?

Comment: no...see....`queueArray[]` is array holding the data for BT, `queueArray[leftNodeIndex]` just fetches the data for left child of the `root`!...u getting my point?

Comment: I'll take your input as an example, you create root `0`, create `1` and `2` and set them as the left and right child of `0`, in the next loop, you create `1` again and set its children, but you didn't set the children of the node you created in the previous loop. As I can see this is the problem.